# ws.write = (result.join(',') + '\n'); && TypeError: result.join is not a function ...how i solve this type error

Tags: javascript

help to solve in this javascript problem. Give me clear documentation about (join).

```
function main() {
const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

const a = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(aTemp => parseInt(aTemp, 10));

const b = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(bTemp => parseInt(bTemp, 10));

const result = compareTriplets(a, b);

ws.write = (result.join(',') + '\n');

ws.end();
```

}

Comment: what is the output of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear documentation for [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
const result = compareTriplets(a, b);
```

Not sure what compareTriplets is but based on the word compare I am assuming it returns a boolean. You are trying to join a boolean expression. If you want one string containing of A and B then put A and B into an array and then use join. But with so little information it is hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Based on your code I am *assuming* A and B both are arrays. If you want to join the elements together do this. Also assuming result is a boolean.

```
function main() {
const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

const a = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(aTemp => parseInt(aTemp, 10));

const b = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(bTemp => parseInt(bTemp, 10));

const result = compareTriplets(a, b);

if(result){
     ws.write = (a.join(',') + ',' + b.join(',') + '\n');
}
ws.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same issue in a problem on Hackkerank,what i was doing wrong was that i was returning results as "return(scoreOfA , scoreOfB)"  but the correct format was "return([scoreOfA,scoreOfB])" as it is using "join" which takes an array as an input .

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
let scoreA=0,scoreB=0;

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
if(a[i] > b[i]){ scoreA += 1}
else if(a[i]< b[i]){ scoreB += 1}
}
return ([scoreA,scoreB])
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has encountered this issue while doing a test on Hackerrank using javascript. They should not use console.log in the middle of the loops instead they should create an array and push console.log data into that array and then return that array at the end of the function.